# Error: data type must provide an itemsize?

Tags: python, visual-studio, numpy, types, anaconda

I have been working on this code for a while and this error never appeared before in m equation !! I don't know why but i think there is something in Anaconda . r_1 and r_2 are position vectors with 3 values for each of them , t_1 and t_2 are time for each position . m should give a number.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import *
r_1=[]
for i in range(3):
    v=input("Elemnts1:  ")
    r_1 = append(r_1,v)
print(r_1)
r_2=[]
for i in range(3):
    v=input("Elemnts2:  ")
    r_2 = append(r_2,v)
print(r_2)
Delta_theta=float(input("Delta_theta="))
t_1=float(input("t_1="))
t_2=float(input("t_2=")) 
Delta_t= t_2 - t_1

def orbit_determination(r_1,r_2,Delta_theta,Delta_t):
    mu=398600.0
    r1_mag=np.linalg.norm(r_1)
    r2_mag=np.linalg.norm(r_2)
    m=(mu*(Delta_t)**2)/(2*np.sqrt(np.dot(r_1,r_2))*np.cos(Delta_theta/2))**3


m=(mu*(Delta_t)**2)/(2*np.sqrt(np.dot(r_1,r_2))*np.cos(Delta_theta/2))**3
ValueError: data type must provide an itemsize
```

Comment: what are the r_1,  r_2,  Delta_theta, t_1 and t_2 that you are using?

Comment: r_1 and r_2 are both position vectors have 3 values for each of them, theta is Angle and t_1 and t_2 are time in 2 position @yann ziselman

Comment: what are their values? your example is not reproducible without the inputs and the expected outputs. If you would, please add them to your post

Comment: Ex:                                                                                                                          
Elemnts1:  4.5
Elemnts1:  2.4
Elemnts1:  7.6
['4.5' '2.4' '7.6']
Elemnts2:  3.2
Elemnts2:  4.5
Elemnts2:  7.6
['3.2' '4.5' '7.6']
Delta_theta=45.7
t_1=3.2
t_2=8.6 @yann ziselman

Comment: Okay thank you @yann ziselman

Comment: I generally advise you no to do 'from numpy import *' mixing namespaces can cause all sorts of errors

Comment: i can't reproduce the error with the inputs you posted. the code runs fine and i get 'm = -6895.707422003119'. will casting v to float resolve the issue?

Comment: Okay , but what can i do if i deleted? i need np library . The code was working good with me but the error appeared after something done in my anaconda and python   @yann ziselman

Comment: will casting v to float resolve the issue?

Comment: Could you explain it more? @yann ziselman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
r_1=[]
for i in range(3):
    v=input("Elemnts1:  ")
    r_1 = np.append(r_1,v)
print(r_1)
```

Should be

```
r_1=[]
for i in range(3):
    v=input("Elemnts1:  ")
    r_1.append(v)
r_1 = np.array(r_1, dtype=float)
print(r_1)
```

Use list append, and convert the result from string input to numeric.

If you still get errors, show the full error with traceback, so we (and you) know where the error occurs.  If it occurs in a long expression (like the `m`), break that up into smaller pieces to better identify the problem.